# Grid caption loads on bottom of table in IE8 when using jquery "html" to dynamically load table

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have a table I load dynamically on a website when a button is clicked.

For some reason, in IE8, when I click the button the table's CAPTION markup loads at the bottom of the grid.

The problem is due to this line of css:

```
vertical-align:bottom;
```

If I remove it it, I'm fine.  I'm just curious if anyone knows the specific reason why this happens.

BTW, "IE sucks" is not specific enough.

You can see a full markup of an example below, or [click here](http://home.windstream.net/ray023/cssQuestion/IE8issue.htm) to see it in action:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Table Test</title>

  <style type="text/css">
   .grid caption {
   background-color:#005abb;
   color:#FFFFFF;
   padding:0 0.25em;
   vertical-align:bottom;
   }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $( "#_button" ).click(function() {     
     var newTableText = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" class="grid"><tbody><caption>Now I\'m on da bottom</caption><tr class="gridHeader"><th>Code</th><th>A</th><th>P</th><th>R</th><th>RM</th><th>Totals</th><th>Percentages</th></tr><tr class = "gridRow"><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>50%</td></tr><tr class = "gridAlternatingRow"><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr></tbody></table>';     
     $( "#_table" ).html(newTableText);
    return false;
   });
   });//End of document ready
  </script>
 <body>

 <button id="_button" type="button">Click Me and watch the caption move to bottom</button>
 <div id="_table" style="width: 700px;">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" class="grid"><tbody><caption>I'm on top</caption>
  <tr class="gridHeader"><th>Code</th><th>A</th><th>P</th><th>R</th><th>RM</th><th>Totals</th><th>Percentages</th></tr>
  <tr class = "gridRow"><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>50%</td></tr>
  <tr class = "gridAlternatingRow"><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
  </tbody></table>
 </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: good job on posting a full example, makes questions of this kind really quick to answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple fix is to specify a [DOCTYPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctype). A `DOCTYPE` tells the browser which set of rules you're playing by. Without it, IE will revert to `quirks mode`, which is essentially the IE 5.5 rendering engine. This will cause many strange side effects, including what you're observing.

I took your example and added the following, and it works fine in IE9 (and IE9 in IE8 mode):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Also, it's important to note that IE requires that nothing proceeds the`DOCTYPE`, otherwise quirks mode will be triggered. White space is OK, but no comments or other markup.